# How to Show tables using DXL scripts?

Tags: ibm-doors

Am trying to replicate the main column (Object Heading the Text) using dxl. Am able to get the object text and object heading. (Missing change bars and links though). Not even a single table cell is detected, what am I missing? How to get the missing change bars and links too?

```
void showObjText(Object obj)
{
 bool bTableCell = cell(obj)

 if(bTableCell == true)
 {
    print "Table Cell! \n"
    displayRich("Am atleast finding tables")
 }

 if (obj."Object Heading" "" != "")
 { 
    font(getCanvas, level(obj), 1)
    displayRich(number(obj) " " obj."Object Heading" "")
 }
 if (obj."Object Text" "" != "")
 { 
    font(getCanvas, level(obj), 0)
    displayRich(richTextWithOle(obj."Object Text"))
 }
}

showObjText(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a big task you have here. There are some more features that you will have to deal with, e.g. indentation, user specific fonts... Suspicions? oh no, they are not shown in the main column. Mimic all menu items in module Explorer -> view -> show etc. etc.

DOORS tables consist of

- one "table" object for the table
- one "row" object for each row. These row objects are children of the table object
- one "cell" object for each cell in a row. These cell objects are children of their respective row object.

So, in the DOORS module explorer there is one line for each "table" object (switch off View->Show->table cells to see this), and you will have to gather the children manually in a loop. I have no idea though how you can paint such a table using DXL.

Change bars are calculated based on time stamps. You may want to create your own changebar column using the perm changebar(set). Otherwise I think you may be able to use the perm "bool modified (Object)" to detect whether the object should be yellow, but I think you will also have to check all attribute definitions whether a change of the attribute shall affect the change bar. But I did not find any perm for "unsaved(Object)"

Links are quite easy to detect, you must use the loops "for Link in Object" and "for LinkRef in Object" to detect whether a link exists. But again I'm not sure how to draw the link symbols and exactly how to calculate when to draw hollow triangles and when to draw filled triangles.

All in all, I'm not really sure whether the main column can be completely mimicked with DXL